# What is the purpose and meaning of taking the 't Hooft parameter to infinity?

Tags: string-theory, feynman-diagrams, holographic-principle, large-n

I am following Hong Liu's MIT 8.821 *String Theory and Holographic Duality* [lectures](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/). He starts discussing the large-$N$ expansion in the context of a hermitian matrix model described by the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{g^2}\text{Tr} \left\{\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi+\frac{1}{4}\Phi^4\right\},$$

where $g$ is the coupling constant and $\Phi$ is a $N\times N$ hermitian matrix. He shows that the large-$N$ limit of this model only makes sense when we consider the 't Hooft parameter

$$\lambda_\text{'t Hooft}=g^2N,$$

and take the $N\rightarrow\infty$ limit while keeping $\lambda_\text{'t Hooft}$ fixed.

At some point in the [lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/video-lectures/structure-of-large-n-expansion/), a student asks a question regarding whether $\lambda_\text{'t Hooft}$ should be a small parameter or not, and Liu remarks that it does not matter, and later on in the course he will eventually take the limit $\lambda_\text{'t Hooft}\rightarrow\infty$.

My question is what is the point in considering the limit $\lambda_\text{'t Hooft}\rightarrow\infty$? What does it mean physically? Is it regarding some sort of a weak-strong coupling duality?

Comment: I don't know about that toy model. But in $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM, changing the 'tHooft coupling corresponds to changing $\alpha^\prime$ in the bulk.

Comment: He discusses the limit in a [later lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/lecture-notes/MIT8_821S15_Lec18.pdf).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/798210/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @bolbteppa, in the lecture note [Chapter3:DualityToolbox](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/lecture-notes/MIT8_821S15_Lec18.pdf) Liu answers this question. Taking the limit $N\rightarrow \infty, \lambda_{t'Hooft}\rightarrow\infty$ corresponds to the semi-classical gravity limit. This means that strongly coupled $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM is dual to classical gravity!